# Realm android not generating mediator

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to make a library for android that can interact with a realm database which is present into the asset/ folder of the app.

This is the exception at runtime:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.TranslationModuleMediator

I searched online and checked that kapt was declared before realm-android plugin but nothing changed.

What am i missing?

#### library plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    //...


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    kapt 'io.realm:realm-annotations:5.4.0'
    kapt 'io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:5.4.0'
}
```

#### realm object

```
import io.realm.RealmObject
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey


open class TranslationModel : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var key: String = ""
    private var languageKey: String = ""
    var value: String = ""

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$key $languageKey $value"
    }
}
```

#### realm module

```
import io.realm.annotations.RealmModule

@RealmModule(library = true, classes = [TranslationModel::class])
class TranslationModule
```

Comment: Try removing Realm dependencies from the dependencies block

Comment: thanks for the response @EpicPandaForce - i added later because i was disperate so removing does not resolve the issue

Comment: Does the main project also apply the Realm plugin?

Comment: sadly yes. double checked

Comment: Did you figure this out? Unfortunately I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: me too mate :/ !